# How do use a specific responses in a post return

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a post to a Server which can return res {success: true}

[image]

In my post if I receive this response I  am trying to active

this.successPost = true;

this.invitePost = false;

Only on this exact response. res {success: true}

My ts code always return the if and never the else on any res response.

ts

```
async sendInvite() {
  let formData = {
    "firstName" : this.data.firstName,
    "lastName" : this.data.lastName,
    "email" : this.data.email
  };
  this.httpClient.post<any>('https://8618' + formData, { 
    headers: { 'x-authorization-token': 'XXXXXXXXXX' }}   
    )
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => { })
    ).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log ("res", res);
          let response = JSON.stringify(res);
            console.log ("response", response);
            if (res = {success: true} ) {
                this.presentToast(response);
                this.successPost = true;
                this.invitePost = false;
              } else {
                this.presentToast(response);
              }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {  // fire on offline
          console.log("err.error", err.error);
          this.presentToast(err.error);
        }  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to not to stringify your response object and just use it as it is. And use equality operator(===) instead of assignment operator.

```
    async sendInvite() {
  let formData = {
    "firstName" : this.data.firstName,
    "lastName" : this.data.lastName,
    "email" : this.data.email
  };
  this.httpClient.post<any>('https://8618' + formData, { 
    headers: { 'x-authorization-token': 'XXXXXXXXXX' }}   
    )
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => { })
    ).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log ("response ", response );
            if (res.success === true) {
                this.presentToast(response);
                this.successPost = true;
                this.invitePost = false;
              } else {
                this.presentToast(response);
              }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {  // fire on offline
          console.log("err.error", err.error);
          this.presentToast(err.error);
        }  
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  had to change .subscribe(
        response => { to .subscribe(
        res => {. and then worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are assigning value in if condition.

Changing `if (res = {success: true} )` to `if (res === {success: true} )` should do for you. But then you might face another problem because you are stringifying the response.

Your final if condition should be like `if (res === '{"success": true}' )`

Hope it helps.